# `Timestamp` and `Time` getting automatically converted

Tags: java, android, mysql, hibernate, timestamp

I am connecting to a REST API developed by my self (built using `Jersey` and `Hibernate`) using my mobile app. I save there the record created time and last updated time, which are botg `timestamps` in the database, even though they are identified as `java.util.Date` in my Hibernate implementation. Below is how I save from mobile.

```
Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.setIdpatient(idPatient);

UnitType unitType = new UnitType();
unitType.setIdunitType(idUnitType);

Units units = new Units();
units.setPatient(patient);
units.setUnitType(unitType);
units.setUnitMeasurement(hba1c);
units.setDateCreated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());
units.setLastUpdated(Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());

restCallSaveUnits(units);


private void restCallSaveUnits(Units units) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestCommon.URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    UnitsEndPoint endPoint = retrofit.create(UnitsEndPoint.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = endPoint.saveUnit(units);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            try {
                String saveMessage = response.body().string();

                Log.d("UNIT_ACTIVITY", " SAVE_MESSAGE " + saveMessage);
                Toast.makeText(context, saveMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                isWeightLoaded = true;
                isHeightLoaded = true;
                isGluLoaded = true;
                isHbLoaded = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

When setting up the time, I get the current timestamp. This is done by `Common.getSQLCurrentTimeStamp())` which I have mentioned the method below.

```
public static java.sql.Timestamp getSQLCurrentTimeStamp()
{
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp t= new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(t);
    return t;
}
```

My Timezone is GMT +5.30. The server is `Amazon EC2` and the database is `Amazon RDS - MySql`. No matter what, the time is always being saved with additional +5.30H. That means, if the time sent to server is `13:30`, what it saves is `18:30`. When it returns the data, I am getting `Timestamps` as a long value and the time is as what server saved, `18:30`. The same goes with `Time` fields as well.

I have tried number of ways to solve this, non really worked. It seems like the time is already changed when the server receives it, because I printed it before it get actually saved in database.

My app will be for the use of users from different countries (because it will be on PlayStore) and I can't figure out how to fix this issue with `timestamp` and `time`. Any idea?